# Unable to properly display Twitter Bootstrap glyphicons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, glyphicons

I was working through the [Angular.js](http://angularjs.org/) Todo application video tutorial and I encountered a problem including the Twitter Bootstrap 3 glyphicons in the index.html file (the icons show up as non-descriptive images, both in Chrome and in Firefox).

This is how I am adding the bootstrap and bootstrap-glyphicons css files in index.html:

```
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="todo.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="todo.css">
</head>
```

And this is how I am adding the required glyphicon later in the file:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <input type="text" ng-model="formTodoText" ng-model-instant>
  <button class="btn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Add</button>
</form>
```

The bootstrap-glyphicons fonts files are in bootstrap/css/fonts. Specifically, the files are:

1. glyphiconshalflings-regular.eot
2. glyphiconshalflings-regular.otf
3. glyphiconshalflings-regular.svg
4. glyphiconshalflings-regular.ttf
5. glyphiconshalflings-regular.woff

Any thoughts on what to do to properly access the icons? Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would first check the versions on your libs.

If you are using a version before [**this pull request**](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/8332) you may be pointing to assets that don't exist. The Bootstrap 3.0.0-wip branch has abstracted glyphicons out to **[this repo](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-glyphicons)**.

I would also preceed the URL asset paths with a `/` to invoke from base URL.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css">
```

On the offical glyphicons lander, an example uses `<span></span>` rather than `<i></i>`

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
```

It is possible they changed that convention.

**EDIT**

In the source you will see the absolute paths of the assets. Double check that your `fonts` directory is on the same level as the `css` directory.

```
src:url('../fonts/glyphiconshalflings-regular.eot');
```

Comment: @Alexandra In the source you will see the absolute paths of the assets. Double check that your `fonts` directory is on the same level as the `css` directory.

Comment: Regarding your three suggestions: 1. I have just downloaded the libraries today from Bootstrap's website, so they should be the most up to date; 2. adding "/" to the asset paths actually prevents the assets from being accessed, so I left the paths the way they are; 3. replacing <i></i> with <span></span> did not seem to make any difference. I don't know if this matters, but "glyphicon glyphicon-minus/plus" work, other icons tried do not ...

Comment: `/` does not "prevent" anything. What it seems like you are running into is an issue with pathing.

Comment: You were right about the fonts and css directories not being on the same level - this fixed my problem.